# Pinescript : How to get previous EMAs cross values

Tags: pine-script

We have inbuilt functions for crossover and crossunder boolean results. However I would like to know the value of the script during those cross and then calculate the price difference between the latest value and crossover values. How can I achieve that?

Thank you,
Prateek

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the value when a condition is met (in your case, the value of `Close` when EMA is crossed) you can use the `ta.valuewhen()` function.

From the [documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_valuewhen):

> Source series value when the condition was true on the n-th most recent occurrence.

For example, you can use it to return the `Close` price when EMA is crossed:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

slow = ta.ema(close, 7)
fast = ta.ema(close, 14)

// get value of close
closePriceOnCrossEma = ta.valuewhen(ta.cross(slow, fast), close, 0)


plot(closePriceOnCrossEma)
```

You can now use this value to compare it with any other value you wish.